# Yii2 Отображение собственных операций для пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

В модели OperationSearch записан следующий код:

```
 $query = Operation::find()->select('');

        $query->joinWith('category');
        $query->joinWith('operationType');
        $query->where(['user_id'=> Yii::$app->user->getId()]);
        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            //'pagination' =>  ['pageSize' => $pageSize],
            'pagination' => false,
        ]);
```

В представление возникает следующая ошибка. Подскажите как ее решить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для `user_id` не указана таблица

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В запросе вам нужно для `user_id` добавить таблицу в которой находится этот столбец.

```
->joinWith('operationType')
->where(['operationType.user_id' =>  ваш id])
```

И в дальнейшем не вставляйте код картинкой.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает *)

Comment: @YuraZelinski если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его как правильный